# How to use CDNs when a site is hosted in Dropbox?

Tags: jquery, dropbox, cdn

I'm trying to use an example jquery-mobile page as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p>Hello world</p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

while hosting this file in my Dropbox public folder as `~/Dropbox/Public/index.html`.

When I try to access the file locally (e.g. `file:///home/<USER>/Dropbox/Public/index.html`) everything works alright.

When I try to access the file using the public link (e.g. `https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/<DROPBOX_ID>/index.html`) it doesn't pull jquery files and the page is not displayed properly. This problem is not specific to jquery and exists in any other CDN as well.

I can download the files to my local machine and host them in Dropbox (e.g. `file:///home/<USER>/Dropbox/Public/js/`) and it works as expected but I would like to use CDNs for not wasting Dropbox bandwidth and also for being able to easily upgrade library versions.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you be more specific about "it doesn't pull jquery files"? What does the DOM inspector say about the script elements, what does the network inspector say about the load requests?

Comment: @Bergi Hmm, that was just my guess that it wasn't pulling the files. I have now checked network inspector and localhost is pulling all 4 files while the Dropbox hosted one is only pulling `index.html`. I don't know what I should look for in DOM inspector.

Comment: Either the script tags don't exist in the DOM, or you should see some errors/warnings about *why* they didn't get loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is probably refusing to load non secure content (jquery) into a page served from a secure location (your dropbox hosted page)

Change the jquery link to use https and you should be ok (alternatively use a procotol relative link (//code.jquery.com) and the browser will pick http or https as appropriate.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much. One minor annoyance is that this time protocol relative links doesn't work for local files which I usually use for development. Do you happen to know how to fix this?

Comment: Ah yes, protocol relative doesn't work when accessed over file:///. Not much you can do about that (short of running a webserver locally)

Comment: Web server sounds like a good idea. I started using `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` (or `python -m http.server` in python3) in my public folder and it seems to work great with protocol relative links. Thanks again.